# gcd(a,b)=d. Let us have prime numbers k, l so that gcd(ak,bl) = d. Is this valid for all prime numbers?

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

Let us have two numbers, `a, b`, so that `gcd(a,b)=d`.

Let us have two prime numbers `k,l` so that `gcd(ak, bl)=d`.

Is this valid for all prime numbers or is there any conditions that must be met?

I guess that it is valid for all prime numbers except those that are divisors of `a` and `b`, i.e. `k`cannot be the prime number which is also divisor of `b` and `l`cannot be the prime number which is also divisor of `a`, but I do not know how to prove it.

Could anyone help? Thank you.

Comment: Try some examples. Maybe $a=6$ and $b=10$. What can the prime numbers $k$ and $l$  be to get $gcd(6k,10l)=2$?

Comment: Are you asking whether $\gcd(a,b)=d$ implies $\gcd(ak,bl)=d$ for all $a,b,k,l\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $k$ and $l$ primes?

Comment: @ndhanson3, I tried the examples, but I just cannot figure out the mathematical proof for that

Comment: @Ellefee, I am asking what is the mathematical proof for the conditions  that must be met so that gcd(ak,bl)=d for when gcd(a,b)=d.

Comment: @ZuzanaTelefony What examples have you tried? Have you found any patterns? 

You need to have an idea of what the conditions are before trying to prove anything, so let's back up and see what they might be.

Comment: @ndhanson3, e.g. for your particular a=6 and b=10 ... k and l can be practically every prime number the prime numbers included already in a and b. (e.g. k=3 and l=7 or k=31 and l=37. BUT NOT k=5 and l=3)

Comment: @ZuzanaTelefony Add your conjecture/hypothesis/guess to the question!

Comment: Cancelling $\,d\,$ yields $\,\gcd(ak,bl) = d \!\iff\! \gcd(\bar ak,\bar bl) = 1\,$ for $\,\bar a = a/d,\, \bar b = b/d,\,$ then apply the linked  dupe using $\,\gcd(\bar a, \bar b) = 1 = \gcd( k,l)\ \ $